# Unity UI not working properly ONLY on Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have been working on figuring out what is going on with my game's UI for at least two days now, and no progress.

Note that this is a mobile game, but I was asked to build for Windows for visualization and presentation purpose.

So the problem is that when I run my game on the Unity Editor, Android, iOS and Mac platforms the UI works just perfect, but then when I run the game on Windows the UI still works fine UNTIL I load a specific scene.

This specific scene is a loading screen (between main menu and a level) when the level finished async loading, a method called `MoveObjects` is called in a script in the loading screen, to move some objects that where spawned in the loading screen scene into the level scene (this is not the issue though, since I already try without this method and the problem on the UI persist).

Once the logic of this `MoveObjects` method is done, a start button is enabled in the loading screen, for the player to click and start playing (I did try moving the start button to the level scene, since maybe it not been a child of the currently active scene could be the issue, but the problem still persist). Is at this point that the UI is partially broken, what I mean with this is, that I can see buttons (and some other UI elements like a scrollbar) changing color/state when the mouse moves over them, but I cannot click on them anymore (the button wont even change to the pressed state).

Also note that I tried creating a development build to see if there was any errors in the console, and I notice that this problem is also affecting the old UI system, so I was not able to interact with the development console anymore.

Also also, note that if I grab and drag the scrollbar before this issue appear, and I keep holding down on the scrollbar until this happens, the mouse gets stuck on the scrollbar, meaning that I cannot interact with the UI anymore, but the scrollbar will still move with the mouse.

- I already check that this things are not the source of the problem:

  - Missing EventSystem, GraphicRaycaster or InputModule.
  - Another UI element blocking the rest of the UI.
  - Canvas is `Screen Space - Overlay` so there is no need for a camera reference.
  - I only have one `EventSystem`.
  - `Time.timeScale` is 1.

I am not sure what else I could try, so if anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

P.S: I am sorry to say that I cannot share any code or visual material or examples due to the confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

A major source for a non-working UI for me has always been another (invisible) UI object blocking the raycast (a transparent Image, or a large Text object with raycast on).

Here's a snippet I put together based on info found elsewhere, I often use it to track objects that are masking the raycast in complex UI situations. Place the component on a text object, make sure it's at least few lines tall, as the results will be displayed one under another.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
public class DebugShowUnderCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text text;
    EventSystem eventSystem;
    List<RaycastResult> list;
    void Start()
    {
        eventSystem = EventSystem.current;
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        text.raycastTarget=false;
    }

    public List<RaycastResult> RaycastMouse(){
         PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData (EventSystem.current)   {  pointerId = -1, };
         pointerData.position = Input.mousePosition;
         List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
         EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);
         return results;
     }
    void Update()
    {
        list= RaycastMouse();
        string objects="";
        foreach ( RaycastResult result in list)
            objects+=result.gameObject.name+"\n";
        text.text = objects;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for trying, and I don't mean to sound rude, but I am sure that this is not the problem, considering the fact that 1. It only happens in Windows (if this was the issue it should happen in all platforms) and 2. The hierarchy of the loading screen is not that complex, so I was sure that this was not the case. I still tried you script though, and it confirm that there is no invisible object blocking the button.

Comment: I guess it doesn't hurt to check. I am not aware of any system-specific differences unfortunately